# How to avoid Asterius `ahc-link` polluting the source directory?

Tags: haskell, build, ghc-asterius

I'm using `ahc-link --output-directory _build`, which produces a bunch of build artifacts in the `_build` directory as expected:

```
_build/
├── default.mjs
├── main.mjs
├── main.req.mjs
├── main.wasm
├── main.wasm.mjs
├── rts.autoapply.mjs
├── rts.closuretypes.mjs
├── rts.constants.mjs
├── rts.eventlog.mjs
├── rts.exception.mjs
├── rts.exports.mjs
├── rts.float.mjs
├── rts.fs.mjs
├── rts.funtypes.mjs
├── rts.gc.mjs
├── rts.heapalloc.mjs
├── rts.integer.mjs
├── rts.jsval.mjs
├── rts.memory.mjs
├── rts.memorytrap.mjs
├── rts.messages.mjs
├── rts.mjs
├── rts.modulify.mjs
├── rts.reentrancy.mjs
├── rts.scheduler.mjs
├── rts.setimmediate.mjs
├── rts.stablename.mjs
├── rts.stableptr.mjs
├── rts.staticptr.mjs
├── rts.symtable.mjs
├── rts.time.mjs
├── rts.tracing.mjs
├── rts.unicode.mjs
└── rts.wasi.mjs
```

However, it also pollutes the source directory with the following intermediate build artifacts:

```
?? src/Hardware/MOS6502/Emu.hi
?? src/Hardware/MOS6502/Emu.o
?? src/main.hi
?? src/main.o
```

Is there some other flag I need to pass to `ahc-link` to put these files under `_build` as well?